# how to change type of a value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do geomap of a value in Elasticsearch but the value type of the `client_location` is set as a string and I would like to change it to `geo_point`. When I run the following I am getting:

```
#curl -XGET "http://core.z0z0.tk:9200/_all/_mappings/http?pretty"
{
  "packetbeat-2015.12.04" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "http" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "beat" : {
            "properties" : {
              "hostname" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "bytes_in" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "bytes_out" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "client_ip" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "client_location" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "client_port" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "client_proc" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "client_server" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "count" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "direction" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "http" : {
            "properties" : {
              "code" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "content_length" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "phrase" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "ip" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "method" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "notes" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "params" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "path" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "port" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "proc" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "query" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "responsetime" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "server" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "status" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
              "type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the following command to change the type of the value from string to `geo_point` I am getting the following error:

```
# curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_all/_mappings/http" -d '
> {
> "http" : {
>         "properties" : {
>           "client_location" : {
>             "type" : "geo_point"
>           }
>         }
>   }
> }
> '
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"merge_mapping_exception","reason":"Merge failed with failures {[mapper [client_location] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type[geo_point]]}"}],"type":"merge_mapping_exception","reason":"Merge failed with failures {[mapper [client_location] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [geo_point]]}"},"status":400}
```

Any suggestion how should I correctly change the type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, once you've created a field you cannot change its type anymore. The best thing to do is to delete the index and recreate it properly with the adequate mapping.

Another temporary solution if you don't want to delete your index immediately, is to create a sub-field of your existing field:

```
# curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_all/_mappings/http" -d '{
  "http": {
    "properties": {
      "client_location": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
          "geo": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And then you can access it in your queries using `client_location.geo`.
Also note that you have to re-index your data in order to populate that new sub-field... which means you might just as well delete your index and re-create it properly.

**UPDATE**

After installing Packetbeat you need to make sure to install the packetbeat template yourself as described here (i.e. it is not done automatically):
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/packetbeat-getting-started.html#packetbeat-template

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/packetbeat' -d@/etc/packetbeat/packetbeat.template.json
```

Comment: these indexes are created by the packetbeat. On the kibana the mapping is correct however the elasticsearch the mapping has wrong type. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Can you update your question with the templates that have been installed in your ES? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template`

Comment: I don't seam to have any templates installed.

Comment: That's how it looks like, indeed. The template should look like this one: https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/packetbeat/etc/packetbeat.template.json

Comment: after creating the indexes on kibana I get this notice where it says that I should be able to change the type using the ES api: This page lists every field in the [packetbeat-]YYYY.MM.DD index and the field's associated core type as recorded by Elasticsearch. While this list allows you to view the core type of each field, changing field types must be done using Elasticsearch's Mapping API

Comment: Yes, but what you see in Kibana is the mapping **already** created in ES. Which means that if you want to change something you need to act **before** the index gets created in ES. Kibana is merely telling you what it sees. But we're back to the initial problem, i.e. that the packetbeat template. See my updated answer.

Comment: OK, this is a new install so I can always delete everything and recreate it. How can I make sure that the packetbeats templates are loaded?

Comment: You need to do it manually yourself only once. It's not done automatically. But once you've installed the template in ES, you don't need to do it again, unless you upgrade to another version of PacketBeat and the template has changed.

Comment: any sugestion how to install the templates in ES?